# Error in Processing Request 500 when trying to browse a table with phpmyadmin version 4.3.12

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mamp-pro

First updated to latest MAMP and all was good but the php version was not the latest in MAMP so updated to latest php,  4.3.12, then for one particular table I could not open it in browse view, I could open the Structure.
If I searched for one item it would open in browse. Then I searched the id field using between to limit the results and it was inconsistent but roughly it would display results with less than 20 rows.

Then I began deleting columns and again it was inconsistent but around 160 columns was the limit, under that it would open the results in the browse view. It didn't matter if I removed rows in the beginning or the end. I tried to isolate a particular field but no luck there either.

Table Type: MyISAM

Row statistics

- Format:   dynamic
- Collation:    utf8_general_ci
- Rows: 2,520
- Row length:   789 B
- Row size: 884 B

Space usage

- Data: 1.9 MiB
- Index:    232 KiB
- Total:    2.1 MiB

**This problem doesn't exist in phpMyAdmin-4.2.13.2**.

Is this a bug in phpmyadmin 4.3.12?
Is there something wrong with my table?

Comment: Take a look in you apache logs.

Comment: Thanks Corni, you put me on the right path, but wrong log, found it in php_error.log

Was exceeding max execution time, it was set at 30, had to increase it to 120 before the page would load.

Comment: So what has changed from 4.2 to 4.3 that causes a need to increase the execution time so much?

Comment: No idea. But I don't think this is a phpMyAdmin issue. Its more likely in your MAMP/server config.

Comment: I only updated tol the new phpmyadmin and then the issue appears. MAMP is the same config in both phpmyadmin versions.

Comment: I ran into this same problem when I set a table to show me 500 rows. Later the table grew and I was getting these timeouts when trying to simply browse the table. And the worst thing was that I couldn't access the setting to show just 25 rows... Solved by upgrading phpmyAdmin to the latest version that is compatible with my php 5.3, which is phpmyAdmin 4.4.15.2.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade scripts sometimes tend to be error-prone. Maybe you should try a fresh installation? and try [mysqlcheck](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlcheck.html) 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlcheck.html

It should list problems with your database.